# Is there something I can do after not putting a moisture barrier between grade and concrete of a garage?

Tags: garage, vapor-barrier

I built a 3 car garage 7 years ago.  I didn't know at the time that I needed a vapor barrier between grade and concrete;  Is there something I can do to keep the floor from being wet on a regular basis?  I am now getting older and plan to retire here (I will not ask my husband>>>>) and am beginning to worry about sliding.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Maybe thoroseal would work. I would contact them and confirm which product and how it should be applied, though. http://www.thoroproducts.com/products_waterproofing.htm

Answer (score 1):

Possibly dig (or have someone else, with equipment, dig) around the outside and put in a curtain drain to lower the water table in the immediate vicinity of the garage. Or lay a barrier on the surface and add a 2 inch (or so) topcoat over it.

Comment: what type of barrier could I lay over the top? Could I then use that epoxy with the silicon dots on top of it?

Comment: Without adding a concrete topcoat, I don't think **any** barrier on top will work, which is why I specified a topcoat. After the topcoat you can put anything on top of the topcoat that suits you, once it has cured. You'll lose 2" or so of headroom, but it's the only method I can envision working on top of the slab. 6 or preferably 12 mil polyethylene sheeting, on the very carefully cleaned garage floor, and then covered with a fairly low-water concrete mix, fiber-reinforced, carefully damp-cured (a slab with plastic under it can be subject to curling if the top is allowed to dry out.)